# How to recognize implementation as unused?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, abstract-class

I'm creating an `abstract` `class` with an `abstract` `method` that must `return` a `String`.
If it returns `null`, it will be skipped and my `default` code will be used instead. The option will be considered unused.

The implementor must decide whether they want to use them or not, if not, they can leave it to return `null`, as the IDE method stub does.

I require it because I want implementors to know of this method's existence.

**But here is the problem:** `null` is also a valid return. If the code, for whatever reason, returns `null`, it will be unintentionally taken for unused.

If I take `null` for "I don't want to return a `String`", it will take stubs as well..

When they extend my class it will look like this:

```
@Override
public String method(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

How can I accept `String` and `null` and unused, with the default being unused?

Comment: I suggest throwing an Exception for the default. Something like [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)

Comment: Well, you obviously can't use `null` as a special value then. What about making the return type `Optional<String>` instead?

Comment: @Tunaki: Item 57 of Effective Java 2nd ed counsels "Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions". This doesn't sound like an exceptional condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8+<sup>1</sup> you could make it an [`Optional<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html),

```
@Override
public Optional<String> method(int i) {
    return null;
}
```

<sup>1<sub>In earlier versions of Java you can potentially use [Guava Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html).</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to use `Optional.empty()` as a return value to indicate that a method cannot return a result. However, you need a second special value to mean that the method is not implemented. You could use `null` for this, but personally I don't like the idea of a method with return type `Optional` returning `null`. The idea of `Optional` is that it should be used as a return type *instead* of returning `null`.

My preferred solution would be to throw an exception if the method is not implemented, and have a separate `boolean` method indicating whether the exception will be thrown.

```
@Override
public boolean isImplemented() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Optional<String> method(int i) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```